# Title is not shown in using open API

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to get results from my source using open library api.

But only titles are not shown. I have no idea what problems are in my code.

The title appears in web inspector, but doesn't appear in browser.

Help me! Thank you in advance

```
<!-- Sample ISBN Number:
9788968481819
9788966185795
9788956747019 -->


<?php
$ISBN = $_GET['barcode'];
$post_data = array(
"page" => 1,
"search_field1" => "ISBN",
"value1" => "$ISBN",
"maxCount" => 1,
"per_page" => 1,
"collection_set" => 1
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://nl.go.kr/kolisnet/openApi/open.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_exec($ch);

print_r($ch);
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>barcode</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="barcode.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="barcode" ">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<title>` has a particular semantic meaning. Most browsers default to not displaying it (it assumes it belongs in the header). You can overrule it with CSS or have response filtered to change the element to a more browser friendly version.

**CSS**

```
title {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: @happylife No worries! if the answer solved your question, be sure to give it the tick-a-roo so others can readily see that if they have the same issue.

Comment: @happylife ah, under the vote options on the left is the option to [accept answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) using the tick.